# Why is eth.accounts[0] undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, password

I am using the `Geth 1.7` console. I tried unlocking the account using `personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "{top secret password}")` but it failed with the following error: 
`first argument must be the account to unlock`.

I suspect the error might be due to the fact that `eth.accounts[0]` is undefined.

*How do I set up `eth.accounts[0]?`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to create an account first before trying to unlock an account residing at the zeroth element in `eth.accounts`.

To create an account: 
`personal.newAccount('yourPasswordForTheNewAccount')`

You are seeing `undefined` because there is not account to unlock.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a ethereum account.

Please use the following command on the geth console.

personal.newAccount("new passphrase")